# Where to find logs for SVN and access them without root permission?

Tags: apache, svn, logging

Seems like the current svn repo is locked. When I do svn up svn just stays there as if its hanged or something and no option from there except to kill it. Would help looking at the logs to see what's going on.

So where does SVN store it's logs and how to find where their location is configured?

Update 1: Found from the answer to a similar question that the logs are at /var/log/httpd but only root has access to that folder. 
Is there an alternative to update the location of logs to go to a more accessible location?

If I have permission to use svn should hopefully have access to svn logs or atleast via .htaccess redirect for my folder to somewhere else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find it at `/var/log/httpd`

> **Is there an alternative to update the location of logs to go to a more
>   accessible location?**

No I dont think you can do that. You can perhaps create a seperate log file.

Check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging):-

> By activating an “operational logging” feature, you can ask
>   mod_dav_svn to create a separate log file describing what sort of
>   high-level operations your clients are performing.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer so quickly and being flexible on this.